# magento flat rate not working

Tags: configuration, magento-1.7

I am trying to add flat rate for products in magento from `system -> configuration -> shipping methods -> flat rate`. These are the setting :

[image]

But flat rate is not appearing on front end :

[image]

Comment: is this issue got solved?

Comment: nope still having same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the cart shipping quote estimator is showing.  If it is then it will only add flat rate shipping to the total if you select it after getting quote and then click 'Update Quote'.

If thats not the issue then you must have modified something either in your theme to hide, or an extension is breaking your totalling.